# Reading from a USB HID device that behaves like a keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, barcode-scanner, hid

I am trying to read the input from a barcode scanner that behaves like a keyboard using the hidapi (https://github.com/signal11/hidapi). Apparently the OS does not allow me to access the scanner because it behaves like a keyboard and for security reasons the OS owns all the keyboard and mice devices. The manufacturer of this barcode scanner does not provide any drivers. Is there a way to prevent the OS from owning this barcode scanner or maybe a way to turn it into a serial port and read from it?

In case there is no workaround for this, does anyone know a cheap barcode scanner that does not behave like a keyboard so that I can use the hidapi to access it? Or how can I know that a barcode will not behave like a keyboard? It is a very specific question that most sellers don't know how to reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A device that only simulates keyboard input, such as a barcode scanner, does not have a way to control programmatically, rather than an interactive device such as a game controller.

You just wait for the barcode data to be notified as keyboard input data.

It will notify you even if you do not own the device. In other words, you need to own keyboard focus. It is ordinary Windows programming knowledge.

Many keyboard input barcode scanners have the ability to customize prefix / suffix codes that are appended to the front and back to identify barcode data input.

They can be customized by reading the settings barcode.

Check the notified key code one by one in the application program, and if such special data comes, please treat it as barcode data.

Answer (score 0):

By "OS" do you mean Windows? Other operating systems usually provide a means to intercept keystrokes. Linux, for example, has the *input* subsystem which lets you intercept keyboard events like keys being pressed and released. Unfortunately, these leave it to you to convert to ASCII/UTF-8 characters yourself.

An easier option, regardless of OS, may be to look for a barcode scanner that emulates a USB-Serial device. That would appear to the system as COMx in Windows, */dev/ttyUSBx* in Linux, etc. Then you can just read the data from it using a serial port library and not worry about keyboard focus.